# critical point / point closest to origin of f(x,y)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a question in a past exam but i am pretty sure the solution is wrong and wondered if someone could please confirm..

**Question:**

Use $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ to find the point on the place $x+y+z=1$ that is closest to the origin.

**solution**
So i have partially differentiated with respect to $x$ and $y$ and i have

$f_x=2x-(1-x-y)=0$ and $f_y=2y-(1-x-y)=0$

and the $x$ and $y$ values are just the solutions to these questions.

I have $x= \frac{1}{4}$ and $y= \frac{1}{4}$ making $z=\frac{1}{2}$

However the solution has $x= \frac{1}{3}, y= \frac{1}{3}$ making $z=\frac{1}{3}$

Could someone please tell me if $$x= \frac{1}{3}, y= \frac{1}{3}$$ making $z=\frac{1}{3}$
**or**
$$x= \frac{1}{4}, y= \frac{1}{4}$$ making $z=\frac{1}{2}$

Many thanks!!

Comment: It is $1/3$.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: there was an error in differentiation on my solutions, the 2 was missing, now have 1/3 after solving the simultaneous equations. thanks.

Comment: A quick way that you can tell that $ \ (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}) \ $ is incorrect and that $ \ (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}) \ $ is at least plausible is that the closest point to the origin on the plane must lie on the normal vector to the plane that passes through the origin ("closest distance is perpendicular distance").  Normal vectors to the given plane have the form $ \ k \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle \ . $

Answer (score 1):

You should find the critical points of
$$
F(x,y,z,\lambda)=x^2+y^2+z^2-\lambda(x+y+z-1),
$$
and thus find where
$$
F_x=F_y=F_z=F_\lambda=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right but you have two errors:

$$
f_x=2x-(1-x-y)=0 \text{ should be } f_x=2x-2(1-x-y)=0
$$

$$
f_y=2y-(1-x-y)=0 \text{ should be } f_y=2y-2(1-x-y)=0
$$

Comment: I thought it should be $\times 2$!! differentiating something squared should call for multiplying by 2! That should hopefully fix the error i will check it again. thought i must just be doing something wrong.. Thanks

Comment: Now have correct answer as $1/3$! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Lagrange Multiplier](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html)

we have $$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a(x+y+z-1)$$

and $f_x=f_y=f_z=0$